# converting the CSV file to MySQL database Schema

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file to a mysql database schema in Windows in the following way:

```
csvkit --db "mysql://user:password@localhost:8080/database" --insert myfile.csv
```

However, I receive the following error message:

> You don't appear to have the necessary database backend installed for
>   connection string you're trying to use.. Available backends include:
>
> Postgresql: pip install psycopg2 MySQL: pip install MySQL-python
>
> For details on connection strings and other backends, please see the
>   SQLAlchemy documentation on dialects at:

When I tried  `csvsql myfile.csv`, I did not get any errors, but I do not know where the file is generated.

Can you please help me in finding out how to import the CSV data via `csvkit` or `csvsql`?

Comment: Postgresql or MySQL? Can you pls make up your mind? Also, the error message actually makes a suggestion as to what you need to do. Have you tried to follow the guidance?

Comment: i want for mysql.i have tried mysql-python command and installed still issue coming.i want to know is the path to mysql currect

Comment: why tagged with postgresql then if it's a mysql question? Please don't add unrelated tags. Anyway it just seems like you haven't installed one of the components required for the tool to work. Follow the instructions given in the error message. If you think you've already installed it, then maybe it's not configured properly, or you have to restart, or something. Check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.i want to know how to give path of mysql db in the command without having db password.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the answer with CSVKit connection mysql using mysql-connector-python, the syntax is:

```
csvsql --db mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@localhost:3306/dbname --tables tableName --insert yourdocument.csv
```