can't use mysql on csvsql from csvkit
this is my input:
csvsql -d ";"  --query "SELECT ID_PROPOSTA FROM acomp_obras_contratos_medicoes_modulo_empresas WHERE MONTH(DATA_INICIO_MEDICAO_OBJETO_ACOMPANHAMENTO_OBRA) LIKE 10 AND YEAR(DATA_INICIO_MEDICAO_OBJETO_ACOMPANHAMENTO_OBRA) LIKE 2010" acomp_obras_contratos_medicoes_modulo_empresas.csv 

this is the error:
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: MONTH

apparently, csvsql is using sqlite instead of mysql, but I can't force csvsql to use mysql with the flag "--dialect mysql" because of this error:
csvsql: error: The --dialect option is only valid when neither --db nor --query are specified.


you need to connect to mysql https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833608/5193536 so that you can use mysql commands

The --query option uses sqlite3. csvsql supports other databases for importing data from a csv file, but not for arbitrary queries.

Each brand of SQL product has its own set of builtin functions. MySQL supports functions like MONTH() and YEAR(), but SQLite does not. This is natural, because ANSI/ISO SQL documents a very small number of standard functions. Each vendor chooses to supplement these functions with their own idea of what their users need.
The closest function SQLite implements to extract the year and month from a date value is the strftime() function.
Here's a demo, tested using csvkit 1.5.0:
% cat acomp_obras_contratos_medicoes_modulo_empresas.csv 
ID_PROPOSTA;DATA_INICIO_MEDICAO_OBJETO_ACOMPANHAMENTO_OBRA
123;2010-10-01
456;2010-11-01
789;2012-10-01

% csvsql -d ';' --query "
  select id_proposta from acomp_obras_contratos_medicoes_modulo_empresas 
  where strftime('%Y%m', data_inicio_medicao_objeto_acompanhamento_obra) 
  = '201010'" \
  acomp_obras_contratos_medicoes_modulo_empresas.csv
ID_PROPOSTA
123.0

